# Updating images through DispatchQueue not consistent

Tags: swift, swift4

I have a recursive function I am using to simulate an avatar blink through the use of 3 images.  About 40% of the time, the blinking does not occur - that is - the images are not updated.  Could someone let me know what I'm doing wrong?

```js
func blink( _ state: Int = 0) {
    var st = state
    let dly: Double!
    st = st%3
    switch(st) {
    case 0: dly = 4.0 + (Double)(rand(70)) / 10
    case 1: dly = 0.05
    case 2: dly = 0.1
    default: dly = 2.0
    }
    self.avatarView.image = UIImage(named: self.name!+(String)(st+1))
    self.avatarView.setNeedsDisplay()
    delay(dly) { [unowned self] in
        if !self.blinkOn {return}
        self.blink(st+1)
    }
}

func delay(_ delay:Double, weak closure:@escaping ()->()) {
    print("blink", delay)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(
        deadline: DispatchTime.now() + delay, execute: closure
    )
}

func rand(_ num: Int) -> Int {
    return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(num)))
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that the recursion is happening (i.e. blink and delay are called repeatedly and you see the output of the print statement) but the images are not updating?  Or are you seeing a breakdown in the recursion such that blink & delay are not even being called?

Comment: The former.  It is being called.

Answer (score 0):

Try couple of things, this may work.

1. First, make sure `UIImage(named: self.name!+(String)(st+1))` returns proper image.
2. I have executed your code and figured out that code is working properly, but in case 1 and case 2 delay time is too small, so if you increase that delay than you can observe that image is updating.

   ```
   switch(st) {
       case 0: dly = 4.0 + (Double)(rand(70)) / 10
       case 1: dly = 0.3
       case 2: dly = 0.2
       default: dly = 2.0
   }
   ```
3. Make sure this condition working proper.

   ```
   if !self.blinkOn {return}
   ```

Comment: I have executed your code and figured out that  in case 1 and case 2 delay time is too small observe image blink.

Comment: Tried that and now the avatar doesnt blink fully.  The thing with a blink, is that it needs to be fairly quick.  Any slower and t doesnt work visually :-(